# UITableView retain count

Tags: iphone, uitableview, memory

Inside ViewWillAppear I am adding a UITableView to controller's view.

```
UITableView *myTableView_portrait = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 768, 857) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[myTableView_portrait setTag:100];
[myTableView_portrait setDelegate:self];
[myTableView_portrait setDataSource:self];

[self.view addSubview:myTableView_potrait];
[myTableView_portrait release];
```

Printing retain count for this table view inside ViewWillAppear returns 1, but inside `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns 2. Even inside `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` the retain count is 1.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea what is going on here?

Yes!  What is going on here is that you're looking at `-retainCount`, which you should forget that you ever saw.  *waves hand* This is not the method you're looking for.

Follow the [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should **never** rely on the retain count or draw much conclusions of it - at least not for complex things like complex third party objects.

In this case the calling code might retain the table before calling your delegate method and release or autorelease it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when this line happens:

```
[self.view addSubview:myTableView_potrait];
```

myTableView is retained by 1 by its delegate controller.

Comment: But when I print myTableView_potrait retain count just after these lines  [self.view addSubview:myTableView_portrait];
    [myTableView_portrait release];
the retain count is still 1

Comment: @user193545: But, did you try NSLog the count right after **addSubview** and immediately before **[myTableView_protrait release]** ?

Comment: It returns a 2 but after [myTableView_protrait release] line the retain count reduces to 1. After this when I again check the retain count inside tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: it again jumps to 2. Why so?  I am checking the allocations through Instruments and once I push another view and remove the table view from superview, memory is still consumed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Eiko seems to provide a plausible explanation. If you find retain counts vary during different runs, chances are that some complex objects are autoreleasing your object. This will lead to different retain counts at the same point during different runs.

Comment: This is bad advice, because it's encouraging the use of `retainCount`.  **DO NOT USE RETAINCOUNT**.  IT WILL NEVER HELP YOU AND WILL ONLY CONFUSE YOU.